# Textview over Imageview in a fixed position

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I would like to put some textviews over an image in a fixed position.
I tried using relative, contraint and frame layout but what I see in preview does not match on my device.
I tried to use px, sp and dp but it did not help.
Textviews must stay exactly in their position on every device.
Thanks

screen device and android studio layout
[image]

xml CODE ADDED:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".b_command">


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup_conn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/plancia_img"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="USB" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ethernet" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/Radiogroup_cmd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup_conn">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Note on/off" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prog Change" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ctrl Change" />
</RadioGroup>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/plancia_layout"
    android:layout_width="363dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Radiogroup_cmd">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plancia_img"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/plancia"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_yellow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="165dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_f2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="215dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_f3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/val_f4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="315dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#F8F5F5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/basic_value"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: drawable]

Comment: if you use correct constraints you can achieve this, and don't need do you any dp,sp etc , just match the constraint and will work on all screen sizes

Comment: I added XML code

Comment: @SimoneGiusti can you post your whole xml file and also drawables?

Comment: go in the setting and there is an option the display setting called screen size/view mode or maybe something else , it gives you three options small , medium, large , please try all of them  , i am quite sure you will get desired layout for one of them, if you get it, them i tell you how to make it consistent for all the view modes.

Comment: full XML and drawable added

Comment: did you try my comment

Comment: I did not find this option.@AbhinavChauhan

Answer (score 0):

you can try screen height programmatic to your textview according to your requirement for more detailing answer elaborate your question first.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a custom view in which I would simply calculate the necessary coordinates.
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html